# Is there any captcha library for ASP.NET except reCaptcha?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget, captcha

Can you suggest any simple captcha (maybe nuget package) that can be used under asp.net web form? Not ReCaptcha because it is simply non readable.

Comment: most of you're suggesting are for mvc...

Comment: Letters looks badly, client can't read captcha... have you seen it ?

Comment: It tooked 5 mins to install it... if you don't know normal(user friendly) captcha, than leave topic please

Comment: I'm really sorry , I didn't understand what you meant, thought you were talking about the code

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution on codeproject - [ASP.NET Captcha](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8751/A-CAPTCHA-Server-Control-for-ASP-NET) (Though not a nuget package)

If your looking for a nuget package, try this [ASP.NET Helpers package](http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft-web-helpers/) which includes a captcha solution